# Use Javascript to export snapshots from a PDF's bookmarks

Tags: javascript, pdf

I would like to make a PDF bookmarks outline into a series of snapshots of those bookmarks (with their name as the text of the bookmark).

For instance, a PDF with the following 3 bookmarks:

Book_root
  sub_bookmark_1
  sub_bookmark_2

Would turn into 3 snapshots named "Book_root", "sub_bookmark_1", "sub_bookmark_2". The snapshots would be of the view in the PDF that the bookmark points to.

I can program in python and other programming languages, but cant seem to find any practical reference guide on how to start this task.

I don't know yet how to program what I want, but the logic would start similar to this pseudo python code:

```
count = 0
for bookmark in root_bookmark.subtree():
    go_to_bookmark_view()
    count = count+1
    save_snapshot_as_png("c:/exported_pdf/"+bookmark.tittle()+str(count))
```

Where could I check the methods I need, possibly with code examples?

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: How do you intend to use this?

Comment: The plan is to use the javascript then be able to review the bookmarks in the snapshots as if they were a presentation, saving me the trouble of having to select bookmark by bookmark.

Comment: After thinking about your question, I now realize that another thing would be equally useful: A script that when used, jumps to the next bookmark in line, possibly showing a popup with the text of that bookmark. But it should smartly jump to the children if any, so I can review the full pdf bookmarks just by using the same script over and over.

Comment: I will ask this in freelancer and paste the solution script here

Comment: If you intend to do this within Acrobat, some of the js syntax can be found in this article https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript. If you intend to do this dynamically as part of a web service I can probably provide some advice but I would need an example use case.

Comment: Thank you very much IdusOrtus, I realized this ends up being a "small project" so I currently published it in freelancer. Same as I did with other questions, I will post and open source the answer when the selected freelancer finishes the job. https://www.freelancer.com/projects/Javascript-PDF/Simple-solution-for-navigating-PDF.html?updated=true

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using "AHK" (autohotkey) to navigate the menus and go to the next/previous bookmark than selected.

First, with one hotkey, I will expand all the bookmarks in the pdf.
Then, with another two hotkeys, you can use them to go next/previous bookmark, without having to look at the bookmarks for this navigation.

Then you can make the script take a snapshot whenever it reaches the bookmark, and you got the same results as doing it through a pdf embedded Javascript, which would have been far more difficult I think.

Thanks all for your help.